# Derivative of composition function $g \circ f^{-1}$ at the point $x=2$

Tags: derivatives, inverse-function

Let $f(x)= x^3+ x$ and $g(x)= x^3-x$ for all $x \in  \mathrm{R}.$ Find the derivative of composition function $g \circ f^{-1}$ at the point $x=2.$

Let $y= f(x)= x^3+ x$, then $y'= f' (x)= 3x^2+ 1$.

$f'(2)= 13 $ and the function itself at $x= 2$ will be $y (x=2)= 10$. By the inverse function theorem ,
$$ (f^{-1})' (y= 10) = \frac{ 1}{ f'(x=2)} = \frac{ 1} { 13} $$

And $(g \circ f^{-1})' = g'(f^{-1}(x)) (f^{-1}(x))'$

But how to evaluate $g'(f^{-1}(x))$, since directly finding the inverse of $f$ is not a better process here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking from your last line of proof: $(g\circ f^{-1})'(2)=g'(f^{-1}(2))\cdot (f^{-1})'(2)= g'(1)\cdot \dfrac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(2))}=2\cdot \dfrac{1}{f'(1)}=2\cdot \dfrac{1}{4}= \dfrac{1}{2}$ .

Comment: shouldn't it be $\frac {2}{ f' (1)}= 2/4= 1/2 ? $